# How to add tweet and facebook like in colorbox images

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have started using Colorbox plugin ([link here](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox)) to create an image gallery. As shown in the demo 4, elastic transition ([link here](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example4/)), I would like to add a tweet and facebook like button for each image at the bottom of each frame. The intention is to let the user like/tweet per image and not to the gallery set. How can that be made possible?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

For the Facebook button [visit this page here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/). All the code you need to add to implement it is there with a lot of supplied help! :)

As far as Twitter is concerned I haven't used it yet! :)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been four years but I happened to be trying to do this today! What I ended up doing is using the callback "cbox_complete" to then inject the HTML into the DOM (I chose to replace the #cboxCurrent but you could replace/append anything). The problem I'm having is that the tweet requires the image to be on its own page; I can't work out how to add an image to a tweet. And Facebook shows a preview of the image but only when clicking on it a second time.
So I'm not sure how useful adding share buttons to Colorbox will be.